# Problema al subir imagenes desde android a mi servdidor localhost

Tags: php, java, android, json

Estoy programando para subir mis imagenes a mi servidor en una carpeta pero no me sube y sale el siguiente error:

> org.json.JSONException: Value[] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Las veces que las probé (creo unas 10), 4 entraron por `OnResponse` y las demas por `onError` y ya desde ahí siempre entra por `onError` y me muestra ese error que les comento arriba. Yo no he modificado nada de codigo. Y por si acaso, cuando entraba por `onResponse` no me subía ninguna imagen a mi carpeta `../fotos/..` de mi servidor. Muchas gracias por su ayuda, amigos.

Aquí está mi codigo de `php` que seria el webservice que me conecta el android con la base de datos.

```
  <?php
  $host_name = "localhost";
  $database = "base_olx";
  $user = "root";
   $password = "";

  $con = mysqli_connect($host_name,$user,$password,$database);

  $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);

 //$nombre = $json["nombre"];
  $nombre = "nombreestatico";
  $listaImagen = $json["listaImagen"];

  $respuesta = array();

  if(isset($listaImagen)){

     if(is_array($listaImagen)){
       foreach($listaImagen as $imagen){
         $decodedImagen = base64_decode($imagen);
         $return = 
            file_put_contents("../fotos/".$nombre."_".$i.".JPG",$decodedImagen);
         $i++;
         $respuesta["ok"] = 1;
       }
     }
     echo  json_encode( $respuesta);
  }else{
     $respuesta["ok"] = 0;
     echo  json_encode( $respuesta);
  }
?>
```

y aqui esta mi codigo en android studio:

```
 public class AgregarMultiplesImagenes extends AppCompatActivity implements 
  View.OnClickListener {                                                           

 private Button btnSelImagenes,btnSubirImagenes;                                                                                                         
 private ArrayList<String> listaDeImagenes;                                                                                                              
 private ArrayList<String> ListaDeNombres;                                                                                                               
 private ArrayList<String> listaDeRutas;                                                                                                                 
 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;                                                                                                                  

@Override                                                                                                                                               
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                                                                                    
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                                                                                                 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_agregar_multiples_imagenes);                                                                                       
InicializarObjetosForm();                                                                                                                           
inicializarOtrosObjetos();                                                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                                       

  private void inicializarOtrosObjetos() {                                                                                                                

  this.listaDeImagenes = new ArrayList<>();                                                                                                          
  this.listaDeRutas = new ArrayList<>();                                                                                                             
  this.ListaDeNombres = new ArrayList<>();                                                                                                           
  this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);                                                                                                    
 }                                                                                                                                                       

  private void InicializarObjetosForm() {                                                                                                                 

    //enlazando al layout                                                                                                                              
    this.btnSelImagenes = (Button) 
    findViewById(R.id.btnSeleccionarImagenes);                                                                           
    this.btnSubirImagenes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubirImagenes);                                                                               

   //Poniendo eventoss                                                                                                                                 

     this.btnSelImagenes.setOnClickListener(this);                                                                                                       
     this.btnSubirImagenes.setOnClickListener(this);                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                       

  @Override                                                                                                                                               
  public void onClick(View v) {                                                                                                                           

 switch (v.getId()) {                                                                                                                               
     case R.id.btnSeleccionarImagenes:                                                                                                              

         //llamando con un intent al seleccionador de imagenes                                                                                      
         Intent abrirElChooserImagenes = new Intent(this, 
  PickImageActivity.class);                                                                 

  abrirElChooserImagenes.putExtra(PickImageActivity.KEY_LIMIT_MAX_IMAGE, 3);                                                                 

  abrirElChooserImagenes.putExtra(PickImageActivity.KEY_LIMIT_MIN_IMAGE, 3);                                                                 
         startActivityForResult(abrirElChooserImagenes, 
  PickImageActivity.PICKER_REQUEST_CODE);                                                     

         break;                                                                                                                                     
       case R.id.btnSubirImagenes:                                                                                                                    
          this.progressDialog.setMessage("Subiendo imagenes....");                                                                                  
          this.progressDialog.show();                                                                                                               

         subirImagenes();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
         break;                                                                                                                                     
 }                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                       

 private void subirImagenes(){                                                                                                                           

 if(this.listaDeImagenes.isEmpty()){                                                                                                                 
                Toast.makeText(this,"Debe seleccionar 3 
   imagenes",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                                        
                return;                                                                                                                             

 }                                                                                                                                                   

  JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();// el array donde iran todas las 
  imagenes codificadas en Base64                                               
  for(String imagenEncode: this.listaDeImagenes){                                                                                                     
        jsonArray.add(imagenEncode);                                                                                                                
 }                                                                                                                                                   

  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();//Aqui van a ir los parametros 
 que se le van a mandar como POST                                            

  try {                                                                                                                                               
    jsonObject.put("listaImagen",jsonArray);                                                                                                        
  } catch (JSONException e) {                                                                                                                         
    e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                            
  }                                                                                                                                                   
        String url = 
       "http://"+MainActivity.IP+"/Olx/WSProys1/SubirMuchasImagenes.php";                                                             
       JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, 
       jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {                                  
    @Override                                                                                                                                       
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {                                                                                                   
        try {                                                                                                                                




     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.get("ok")
    .toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                         
        } catch (JSONException e) {                                                                                                                 
            e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                    

        }                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                               
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {                                                                                                                   
    @Override                                                                                                                                       
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                                                                                                
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage()
    ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                              
      }                                                                                                                                               
   })      ;                                                                                                                                           

  Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjectRequest);                                                                                                

  this.progressDialog.dismiss();                                                                                                                      

}                                                                                                                                                       

 @Override                                                                                                                                               
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable 
  Intent data) {                                                               
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);                                                                                              

  if(requestCode == PickImageActivity.PICKER_REQUEST_CODE){                                                                                           

    if(resultCode != PickImageActivity.RESULT_OK){                                                                                                  
       return;                                                                                                                                      
    }                                                this.listaDeRutas = 
   data.getStringArrayListExtra(PickImageActivity.KEY_DATA_RESULT);           
    if(this.listaDeRutas != null && !this.listaDeRutas.isEmpty()){                                                                                  
            this.listaDeImagenes.clear();                                                                                                           
            for(int i = 0; i<this.listaDeRutas.size(); i++){                                                                                        
                try {                                                                                                                               
                    Bitmap bitmap = 

MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),Uri.fromFile(new 
File(this.listaDeRutas.get(i))));  
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new 
ByteArrayOutputStream();                                                      

 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);                                                          
                    String bitMapCodificado = 
  Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);                            
                    this.listaDeImagenes.add(bitMapCodificado);                                                                                     
                    File laImagen = new File(this.listaDeRutas.get(i));                                                                             
                    this.ListaDeNombres.add(laImagen.getName());                                                                                    

                } catch (IOException e) {                                                                                                           
                    e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                            
                }                                                                                                                                   
            }                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}
```

Comment: en que clase y línea te marca el error?

Comment: Por las dudas fijate si no es que estás usando JsonArray en lugar de JSONArray ...

Comment: El problema es que tu respuesta obtiene un JSONArray  en lugar de JSONObject , por eso el error : "Value[] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject", te sugiero agregues la respuesta json para agregar una respuesta adecuada. @DavidGarcia

Comment: holaa, gracias por responder, bueno no me marca error, si no que 1) no sube las imagenes al servidor 2) la respuesta entra por onErrorResponse  y entonces yo imprimi el error ese que me llega a ese metodo y me da el error mencionado en la pregunta

Comment: holaaa amigos el punto 1 si ya me sube las imagenes y esl por JsonArray que no me funcaba ahora lo Cambie a JSONArray :) gracias @Juan

Comment: pero les cuento que la respuesta me sigue llegando a onResponse con el mismo error mencionado.arriba

Comment: Del lado del php, antes de mandar la respuesta seteale un header para que el que recibe sepa que es json: header('Content-Type: application/json'); No va a resolver un problema de formato pero si es de interpretación sí, y ademas podes ver el json si le pegas con el navegador.

Comment: holaa @Juan pues le cuento que sigue llegando al onError y con el mismo error y ya puse header('Content-Type: application/json');  antes del echo json_encode($respuesta);

Comment: Para probar, podes cambiar el request de Json object a String, y logueas el response (que será un String en lugar de un JSONObject) lo que te devuelve. Así podes verificar si el json que recibis es el que estás esperando.